# SKProductsRequestDelegate method isn't being called inside class

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, delegates, in-app-purchase

I want to load the `SKProduct`s before the actual page is shown. But I have some difficulties with creating it.

What I thought was to made another class that loads the products, like this:

```
class GetIapInfo: NSObject, SKProductsRequestDelegate {

    var list = [SKProduct]()
    var p = SKProduct()

    let audio = "com.xxx";
    let video = "com.xxx"
    let complete = "com.xxx"

    override init() {
        super.init()

        if SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments() {
            print("starting IAPS")
            let productIdentifiers = Set([audio, vídeo, complete])

            let request = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productIdentifiers)
            request.delegate = self
            request.start()
        } else {
            print("please enable IAPS")
        }
    }

    internal func productsRequest(_ request: SKProductsRequest, didReceive response: SKProductsResponse) {
        print("product request")
        let myProduct = response.products

        for product in myProduct {
            print("product added from ding")
            print(product.productIdentifier)
            print(product.localizedTitle)
            print(product.localizedDescription)
            print(product.price)
        } 
    }
}
```

But this only calls the `init` method and that's it, it doesn't call the `productsRequest` method. Has that something to do with the delegate?

And how am I going to save the products that are going to return in that method? Because I need them later.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You probably should keep around a reference to the `SKProductsRequest` object you created inside your `GetIapInfo.init()`. Your current code will *deallocate* the `request` object the moment the `init` method exists. This might explain why your delegate isn't being called at all ;)

From the [`SKProductsRequest` class documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skproductsrequest):

> Be sure to keep a strong reference to the request object; otherwise, the system might deallocate the request before it can complete.

For instance, create a stored property for it:

```
private let request: SKProductsRequest!
```

Might also be a good idea to track any request related errors by implementing this delegate method as well:

```
func request(_ request: SKRequest, didFailWithError error: Error) {
    print("Request failed: \(error)")
}
```

Comment: I have tried your solution, but it doesn't work. It does the exact same thing as before. Your solution makes sense to me. But it doesn't work unfortunately.

Comment: @da1lbi3 Of course, you also need to keep a reference to the created `GetIapInfo` object in your calling code. Are you doing that?

Comment: Aah thanks! What I did was instantiating the GetIapInfo inside a viewdidload without a strong reference. This wasn't working hah! Now I create a strong reference and it works. Thanks!